# Pandas dataframe column calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace the values in a column by a calulation (which is a multiplcation of comlun values).
like this:

```
    df.loc[:, 'cfit'] = df['cfit'] * df['risk_nr']
```

I get the following message:
*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s*

Is this a correct or false warning of pandas ?
Thnx

Comment: What version of pandas are you running and are you able to post sample data to reproduce your problem as I cannot

Comment: pandas version 0.15.1

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this:

```
df['cfit'] = df['cfit'] * df['risk_nr']
```

or even:

```
df['cfit'] *= df['risk_nr']
```

Regarding your question: I think this is a false warning in this particular case, as `df.loc[:, 'cfit']` should return a view and not a copy. You can turn off the warning with:

```
pd.set_option('chained_assignment', None)
```

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you that it's a false warning.  I've seen that warning before, but it's generally associated with a conditional update not using .loc/row index.

Comment: @BobHaffner, Yep, I think something else is going on there as I don't get the warning for a simple `df.loc[:, 'colname'] = something`. May be the code shown is not the actual one he is using.